# checking condition gives wrong result

Tags: python, python-3.x, conditional-statements

I'm beginner in python. I made simple program using multiple if conditions but there's some issue in this code. If my lifting capability is lower than item's weight and i said no i can't lift that item, it should say "yes you can't ,...." but it rather say : "don't be so lazy,..." 
I don't know why although my logic is correct, i couldn't find any bug.

```
Weights = {
    "table":5, #kg
    "sofa":9, #kg
    "Cupboard":85, #kg
    "Ladder":7, #kg
}
print("How much weight can you lift? ")
lifting_capability = input("Enter your lifting capability"+" ")
lifting_capability_int = int(lifting_capability)
for Objects in Weights.keys():
    Answer = input("Can you lift" + " " + Objects + "? " + "Y/N ")
    Answer_Adjusted = Answer.lower()    
    for Wt in Weights.values():
        if Answer_Adjusted == "y" and Wt > lifting_capability_int:
            print("mmmmm...., i don't think you can lift this much")
            break
        elif Answer_Adjusted == "n" and Wt > lifting_capability_int:
            print("Yes you can't, you know how to keep your backbone in place")
            break
        elif Answer_Adjusted == "y" and Wt <= lifting_capability_int:
            print("Yes, obviously you can, its so light for you")
            break
        elif Answer_Adjusted == "n" and Wt <= lifting_capability_int:
            print("Don't be so lazy, its lighter than you think")
            break
        else:
            print("you think you can, but watch yor feet")
```

Comment: For each key, you are looping through every value in the dictionary, not just checking the value associated with the key under consideration.

Comment: @khelwood thanks, i got it !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are looping twice through your dictionary. Rewrite your code with **one single** for-loop like this:

```
for object, weight in Weights.items():
```

Comment: @HiraHassanAwan if this answers solves your problem, please accept it as the correct answer.